# Reverse the currency value to floating number

Tags: angular, ionic6, currency-pipe

I'm working on a german local based currency input using ionic(Angular). I want to show something like this

[image]

But back end API accepts the value as a floating number.

Ex:- 56.00

what I have currently done is

```
                    <ion-input 
                        #amount="ngModel"
                        name="AMOUNT"
                        [required]="true"
                        [min]="50"
                        [max]="20000000"
                        (focusout)="rollBackTransformAmount()"
                        (focusIn)="transformAmount()"
                        [ngModel]="formattedAmount"
                        (ngModelChange)="transfer.amount=$event; formattedAmount=$event"
                         placeholder="Amount">
                    </ion-input>
```

and in ts

```
  transformAmount(){
    if(!isNaN(this.formattedAmount)){
      this.formattedAmount = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.formattedAmount, 'EUR', 'symbol', '1.2-2', 'de');
    }
  }


  rollBackTransformAmount(){
    // todo
    // this is what I want to implement 
    // get the floating number equivalent for this.formattedValue 
  }
```

**UPDATE** - I was able to come up with some thing like follow

```
 transformAmount(){
    if(!isNaN(this.formattedAmount)){
      this.formattedAmount = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.formattedAmount, 'EUR', 'symbol', '1.0-2', 'de');
    } else {
      this.unFormatCurrencyAmount();
      this.formattedAmount = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.formattedAmount, 'EUR', 'symbol', '1.0-2', 'de');
    }
  }


  rollBackTransformAmount(){
    this.unFormatCurrencyAmount();
    console.log(this.formattedAmount);
  }

  unFormatCurrencyAmount(){
    if(this.formattedAmount){
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      this.formattedAmount = this.formattedAmount.replace(getCurrencySymbol('EUR', 'narrow','de'),'').trim().replaceAll('.','').replace(',','.');
    }
  }
```

Is there any proper way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to don't format the variables in your typescript. You should instead only store the plain floating number and only display it in your input component (using currency pipe) as:

```
<ion-input 
  #amount="ngModel"
  name="AMOUNT"
  type="number"
  [required]="true"
  [min]="50"
  [max]="20000000"
  [ngModel]="formattedAmount | currency:'EUR'"
  (ngModelChange)="transfer.amount=$event;
  placeholder="Amount">
</ion-input>
```

Comment: If we were to go with this approach problem is formatted value will give error on second time it goes through the currency pipe. Also in typescript I am using currency pipe.